# android recognize if call has been answered

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I'm trying to add to my broadcast receiver an if, so I will start a different activity if a call has been answered, to the regular activity I start usually, if the screen has just been turned on.

Now as you can see down here I have the class screenJump starting when the user wakes up phone.

I would like to start a phoneActivity I wrote when the user wakes up phone, but only when a call has been answered.

This is my service now.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver bd;
    public MyService() {
    }

    class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent startupIntent = new Intent(context, ScreenJump.class);
            startupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(startupIntent);
        }
        public ScreenReceiver()
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

        bd = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(bd, filter);

    }


}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't want the startactivity to wrok when a call has been answered

Comment: Please clarify, what you want, unable to understand.

Comment: Mean, if any call came and the user wakes up phone, then you start to want another activity?

Comment: yes, a different one than the default one that is starting now.

Comment: So, here you need to define add another action for phone state also.